# KQL for detecting 'add group' and then subsequent ' add member to group'

Tags: logging, analytics, kql, audit-logging, azure-sentinel

I am fairly early on in my KQL journey and I have set myself a task.

I want to create a query that detects when a new group is created and then a new user is added to said group.

I can get the info I want for each operation easily but how to combine these? Is it even possible?

I have been playing about with Unions and Joins etc but this one is beyond me.

If anyone could take the time ot asssit I would really appreciate it

```
AuditLogs
| where OperationName in ('Add member to group', 'Add owner to group')
| extend GroupName = tostring(TargetResources[0].displayName)
| extend RoleId = tostring(AdditionalDetails[0].value)
| extend UserAdded = tostring(TargetResources[2].displayName)
| extend ObjectId = tostring(TargetResources[2].id)
| extend UserPrincipalName = tostring(parse_json(tostring(InitiatedBy.user)).userPrincipalName)
| extend IPAddress = tostring(parse_json(tostring(InitiatedBy.user)).ipAddress)
| where Identity != "Microsoft Teams Services"`


AuditLogs
| where OperationName has "Add Group"
| extend GroupName = tostring(TargetResources[0].displayName)
| extend RoleId = tostring(AdditionalDetails[0].value)
| extend UserAdded = tostring(TargetResources[2].displayName)
| extend ObjectId = tostring(TargetResources[2].id)
| extend UserPrincipalName = tostring(parse_json(tostring(InitiatedBy.user)).userPrincipalName)
| extend IPAddress = tostring(parse_json(tostring(InitiatedBy.user)).ipAddress)
| union isfuzzy = AuditLogs 
| where OperationName in ('Add member to group', 'Add owner to group') ) on  Identity
```